# How to search all table records and if not exist a record create a new empty?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with year and monthly sales, but some months doesn't have sales and i need to run all table and if doesn't exist create one with zero sales.

This is my database structure

```
CREATE TABLE `MonthlySales` (
  `code` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `Year` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Month` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `SalesQty` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `SalesValue` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `TValue` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `DValue` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `CValue` varchar(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`code`,`Year`,`Month`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Article` (`code`,`Year`,`Month`);

INSERT INTO `MonthlySales` (`code`, `Year`, `Month`, `SalesQty`, `SalesValue`, `TValue`, `DValue`, `CValue`) VALUES
(100000, 2017, 1, '1', '1.6', '', '', '1.11'),
(100000, 2017, 2, '1', '1.6', '', '', '1.11'),
/*Here i need new records with zero values for months 3,4,5,6,7*/
(100000, 2017, 7, '98', '144.2', '', '29.76', '108.78'),
(100000, 2017, 8, '124', '191.65', '', '74.4', '137.64'),
/*Here i need new records with zero values for months 9,10,11*/
(100000, 2017, 12, '7', '11.2', '', '', '7.78'),
(100000, 2018, 1, '2', '3.2', '', '', '2.24'),
(100000, 2018, 3, '4', '6.32', '', '', '4.44'),
(100000, 2018, 4, '8', '12.8', '', '', '8.91'),
(100000, 2018, 9, '18', '28.74', '', '19.2', '19.84'),
(100000, 2018, 10, '19', '30.02', '', '14.22', '20.97'),
(100000, 2018, 11, '2', '3.16', '', '', '2.2'),
(100000, 2018, 12, '2', '3.16', '', '', '2.2'),
(100000, 2019, 1, '14', '22.12', '', '', '15.38'),
(100000, 2019, 2, '8', '12.64', '', '', '8.8'),
(100000, 2019, 6, '47', '74.26', '', '', '51.7'),
(100002, 2017, 1, '14', '54.02', '', '', '41.16'),
(100002, 2017, 2, '12', '46.8', '', '', '35.28'),
/*Here i need new records with zero values for months 3,4 */
(100002, 2017, 5, '20', '78', '', '', '58.8'),
(100002, 2017, 6, '14', '49.92', '', '', '41.16'),
```

I need for for all year and months from 2017 until now.

Comment: I don't know what 'run all table' means, but issues of data display are often best handled in application code

Comment: I do know that the varchar data type has no business being in this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a query that generates all of the rows that we want to return.  We can use a semi-Cartesian product.

We can start with this to return the `year` values:

```
SELECT y.yyyy
  FROM ( SELECT 2017 AS `yyyy` UNION ALL SELECT 2018 UNION ALL SELECT 2019 ) y
 ORDER
    BY y.yyyy
```

And then add a join to another row source to add `month` values for each `year`. We can also add a filter so that rows that have `year` and `month` values from future dates are excluded.

Something like this:

```
SELECT y.yyyy
     , m.mm
  FROM ( SELECT 2017 AS `yyyy` UNION ALL SELECT 2018 UNION ALL SELECT 2019 ) y
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS mm 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
         UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
       ) m
HAVING CONCAT(y.yyyy,'-',m.mm,'-01') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER
    BY y.yyyy
     , m.mm
```

And if we need to generate all of those same rows multiple times, once for each of a given set of `code` values, we can add another join for another semi-Cartesian product:

```
SELECT c.code
     , y.yyyy
     , m.mm
  FROM ( SELECT 2017 AS `yyyy` UNION ALL SELECT 2018 UNION ALL SELECT 2019 ) y
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS mm 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
         UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
       ) m
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 100000 AS code
         UNION ALL SELECT 100002
       ) c
HAVING CONCAT(y.yyyy,'-',m.mm,'-01') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER
    BY c.code
     , y.yyyy
     , m.mm
```

If table `MonthlySales` contains matching rows, and we want to identify rows that don't have a matching row in `MonthlySales` we could do a conditional test with a NOT EXISTS on a correlated subquery,  or an anti-join pattern

```
SELECT c.code
     , y.yyyy
     , m.mm
  FROM ( SELECT 2017 AS `yyyy` UNION ALL SELECT 2018 UNION ALL SELECT 2019 ) y
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS mm 
         UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
         UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
       ) m
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 100000 AS code
         UNION ALL SELECT 100002
       ) c

    -- ant-join pattern to eliminate rows that have a match in MonthlySales
  LEFT
  JOIN `MonthlySales` s
    ON s.`code`   = c.code 
   AND s.`year`   = y.yyyy 
   AND s.`month`  = m.mm
 WHERE s.`code` IS NULL

HAVING CONCAT(y.yyyy,'-',m.mm,'-01') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
 ORDER
    BY c.code
     , y.yyyy
     , m.mm
```

That would give us the rows that are "missing".  We could expand the expressions in the SELECT list to return literals

```
SELECT c.code      AS `code`
     , y.yyyy      AS `year`
     , m.mm        AS `month`
     , '0'         AS `salesqty`
     , '0.00'      AS `salesvalue`
     , ''          AS `tvalue`
     , ''          AS `dvalue`
     , '0.00'      AS `cvalue`  
  FROM ...
```

Comment: personally i wouldnt approach this as a separate step, to add rows that are missing. but thats what this answer does, because that is the question that was asked. i would back up to the process that is putting rows into table.  rather than insert just a subset, and figure out whats missing later, we could generate a complete set of rows, as demonstrated in this answer, but rather than an anti-join , do an outer join to the rowsource to get salesqty, salesvalue, etc.